# Flutter: App crashes when double tap or long press on Cupertino TextField with ProgressDialog

Tags: flutter

I am using [flutter progress dialog library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_progress_dialog) to show progress UI when app is performing something serious IO stuff. But i noticed when we double tap or long press on any Text Input Field, App crashed / shows Red screen in debug.

Here is the related logs:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown building _OverlayEntryWidget-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryWidgetState>#235b1](dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _OverlayEntryWidgetState#faabb):
Invalid argument(s): 26.0

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ProgressDialog file:///Users/bipinvaylu/Documents/Work/Workspaces/xyzapp/lib/main.dart:89:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      double.clamp (dart:core-patch/double.dart:183:7)
#1      _CupertinoTextSelectionControls.buildToolbar (package:flutter/src/cupertino/text_selection.dart:478:72)
#2      TextSelectionOverlay._buildToolbar (package:flutter/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:578:34)
#3      _OverlayEntryWidgetState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:179:34)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
...

====================================================================================================
main.dart - MyApp:

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    return Localizations(
      locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      delegates: <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      child: MediaQuery(
        data: const MediaQueryData(),
        child: ThemeBuilder(
          defaultThemeMode: ThemeMode.system,
          darkTheme: darkTheme,
          lightTheme: lightTheme,
          statusBarColorBuilder: (theme) => HomePage.tabBackgroundColor,
          themes: getThemes(),
          builder: (context, regularTheme, darkTheme, themeMode) {
            return LayoutBuilder(
                //return LayoutBuilder
                builder: (context, constraints) {
              return OrientationBuilder(
                  //return OrientationBuilder
                  builder: (context, orientation) {
                //initialize SizerUtil()
                SizerUtil().init(constraints, orientation);

                return ProgressDialog(
                  orientation: ProgressOrientation.vertical,
                  loadingText: "Please wait...",
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  child: MaterialApp(
                    title: "Xyz app",
                    theme: regularTheme,
                    darkTheme: darkTheme,
                    themeMode: themeMode,
                    home: SplashScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              });
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Text input field setup in other screen as follow:

                    Expanded(
                      child: CupertinoTextField(
                        controller: _userNameTextController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        placeholder: "Friend username",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        prefix: Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9.0, 6.0, 9.0, 6.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withAlpha(70),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

I don't see any proper solution as of now. Please help me here to resolve this issue. Else i might need try and switch over to other library and that some extra work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use a empty MediaQueryData.

Try to replace `const MediaQueryData()` with `MediaQuery.of(context).data`

Answer (score 0):

```
 return MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: [GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate, GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate, localizationDelegate],
  supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
  locale: localizationDelegate.currentLocale,
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: Strings.app_title,
  theme: ThemeData(
      pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      }),
      primaryColor: themeColor.getColor(),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            color: LightColor.theme_purple,
          ))),
  localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
    for (var supportedLocaleLanguage in supportedLocales) {
      if (supportedLocaleLanguage.languageCode == locale.languageCode && supportedLocaleLanguage.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
        return supportedLocaleLanguage;
      }
    }
    return supportedLocales.first;
  },
  builder: (context, child) {
    return FlutterEasyLoading(
        child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: child,
    ));
  },
  home: <Your Widget>
);
```

final themeColor = Provider.of(context);
var localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;

Use MaterialApp() to cover up you app.
Use library   flutter_easyloading: ^2.2.2